com.mongodb.MongoConfigurationException: Failed looking up TXT record for host
I'm trying to configure my mongodb datasource in quarkus 3.11.2 localhost project (jdk 21), but I obtain: Failed looking up TXT record for host  at the startup of the application. Using the same url I can connect to mongo cluster using MongoDB Compass (from my localhost). Im using  mongodb+srv protocol inside my application.properties:
quarkus.mongodb.connection-string=mongodb+srv: etc..
any suggestions?
Thank you.
Im using  mongodb+srv protocol inside my application.properties:
quarkus.mongodb.connection-string=mongodb+srv: etc..
any suggestions?
Thank you.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I had the same issue with quarkus 3.13.3.
It is caused by the newer reactive dns resolver and the mongo cluster mode URI.
This was supposedly "fixed", but it's not, there are still subtle issues with the quarkus reactive layers and mongo client initialization on start up.
You can work around it by using the non cluster mode URI specification.
If using Mongo Atlas specify an older driver version for the connection info and it will list the connection URI you need. It will be longer with more parameters, the main one you should see is the replica set name specified.
Example config:
quarkus.mongodb.connection-string = mongodb://<user>:<password>@shard0.mongodb.net:27017,shard1.mongodb.net:27017,shard2.mongodb.net:27017/?ssl=true&replicaSet=<replicaSetName>&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true&w=majority&appName=<appName>

Quarkus thread with the original issue:
https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/27627
